# xCode 6.4 crashes on El Capitan

Tags: xcode, macos, crash, xcode6, osx-elcapitan

I just downloaded El Capitan today and when I try to add a new view controller to my project, xCode crashes and I am unable to add any view controller to my project with I need. Is this happening to anybody else or does anybody have a fix for this? I have reinstalled xCode 6.4 multiple times and I do not want to use xCode 7 as I do not want to use Swift 2 just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.4 does not work with OS X El Capitan. You need to download the Xcode 7.

Good luck!

Comment: If I upgrade to xCode 7 am I forced to use Swift 2 or is there a way around that?